# Do subsequent onscroll events get canceled when div is modified?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a virtual scrolling mechanism so I can keep the DOM light for large lists. The idea is the content not visible in the main div (content before/after the visible viewport) can be removed from the dom and replaced with an empty div used as a spacer. There is one div with a scrollbar and it contains 3 divs:

- beforeDiv : this is an empty spacer div. rows in this div are above the visible section of the viewport hence we dont need to render them
- middleDiv : this div will have rows that are rendered
- afterDiv: this is an empty spacer div. rows in this div are below the visible section of the viewport hence we dont need to render them

The code snippet shows the virtual scrolling with 1000 rows. Its sort of minimal example of my real code to demonstrate the point. Every 10 rows is consider a "page" and each row is hardcoded to 100px height. I have an onscroll handler that will check if I need to update the 3 divs to resize before/after divs and change the rows that are rendered in middle div. As we scroll down the height of before div will grow and the height of the after div will shrink (both of those divs will be empty and are mainly spacing divs so the scrollbar works correctly).

Here is the issue. When I hit the down arrow one time to scroll it will actually trigger the onscroll event several times for smooth scrolling (run the snippet and hit down arrow one time - you will see the scrolltop changes several times by a few pixels at a time). That is fine. But when I get to a "page" boundary and I adjust the before/middle/after divs it seems to cancel the subsequent scrolls. So when I get to a boundary it does not scroll the full amount and looks very jerky. Lets say the event should have fired 5 times for 1px, 3px, 5px, 6px, 10px for a total of 25px. It will only fire once for 1px and the subsequent scrolls get canceled. I guess because Im modifying the content of the div?

If you hold down the down arrow its fairly smooth but you can still see a slight delay every 10 rows.

Any ideas how I can make the scrolling more smooth?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var ROW_HEIGHT = 100;
  var PAGE_COUNT = 10;
  var data = [];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    data[data.length] = "index " + i;
  }
  
  function min(n,min){
    return n < min? min:n;
  }
  
  function log(msg){
    var logger=$("#logger")[0];
    $(logger).append("<div>"+msg+"</div>")
    logger.scrollTop = logger.scrollHeight;
  }
  
  var scrollInfo = {};
  
  function virtualScroll(){
    var scrollTop = $("#scrollbarWrapper").scrollTop();
    log("scrollTop:"+scrollTop);
    var topRow = Math.floor(scrollTop/ROW_HEIGHT);
    var topPageRow = topRow-topRow%PAGE_COUNT;
    var beforeRows = min(topPageRow-PAGE_COUNT,0);
    var middleRows = 30;
    var afterRows = data.length - middleRows - beforeRows;

    if (scrollInfo != null && (scrollInfo.beforeRows == beforeRows && scrollInfo.middleRows == middleRows && scrollInfo.afterRows == afterRows )){
      return;
    }
    
    log("=====ADJUSTING=DIVS=====");
    scrollInfo = {beforeRows:beforeRows,middleRows:middleRows,afterRows:afterRows};

    $(".middle").empty();
     
    for (var i = beforeRows; i < beforeRows+middleRows; i++){
      $(".middle").append("<div class='row'>"+data[i]+"</div>");
    }
    
    $(".before").outerHeight(beforeRows*ROW_HEIGHT);
    $(".after").outerHeight(afterRows*ROW_HEIGHT);

    $("#scrollbarWrapper").scrollTop(scrollTop);
    $(".middle").focus();
  }
  
  virtualScroll();
  $("#scrollbarWrapper").on("scroll",virtualScroll);
});
```

```css
#scrollbarWrapper{
  display:inline-block;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  overflow:auto;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.row{
  display:inline-block;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

#logger{
  display:inline-block;
  height:500px;
  /*width:500px;*/
  overflow:auto;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scrollbarWrapper" class="scrollbarWrapper">
  <div class="before" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="middle" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="after" tabindex="0"></div>
</div>
<div id="logger"></div>
```

Comment: I modified the script a bit so that when scrolling down it just keeps appending the new records and does not ever remove the before div elements. Interestingly as long as I don't change the height of the before div the issue does not occur (however I cant achieve the goal of keeping the dom light in this way). .

Comment: after days of experimentation it seems like subsequent scroll events get canceled when I do anything that modifies the scrollTop. It makes sense sort of but it is going to really complicate the design since final product is going to be virtual scrolling on variable sized rows.To keep things smooth I need to periodically adjust the scrollTop. Working on some solution where I do that adjustment only after the user stops scrolling for n milliseconds so they wont notice anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I found is that anything that modifies scrolltop will stop the scroll inertia. I redesigned my entire component so that I can avoid having to set the scrolltop. Instead I am just updating the before and after divs to make sure the content in the viewport stays in the viewport correctly. I also found that when I add anything in the dom that is above the scrolltop it will acually cause the scrolltop to change which is why I had the line in my sample code to adjust the scrolltop. Now I do in proper order and I am shrinking before div before I append the new content.